# Calender with events from sqlite for adobe air application

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, events, air, calendar

I am creating an adobe air application for a shop,I want to display a calender with events which has been picked from sqlite database(like a  **To Do** list).I have searched lot but got nothing.Please help me if you have any samples???or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a tutorial for creating a event calendar:

http://www.thetechlabs.com/interfaces/create-a-dynamic-event-calendar-in-flex-builder-3-with-actionscript-30/

Wish it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Flextras Calendar](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=15)?  Flextras is a commercial venture, but the products are free for production use; you'll have to pay if you want the source or if you want help.

There are other commercial Calendar components out there too; but for selfish reasons I prefer ours.